# ASPxUploadControl - preview image before uploading?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

Is there a way by using ASPxUploadControl to have an image get uploaded automatically when you click the ok button after browsing and then get shown a preview of said image but only upload the image to the server officially after you click an ok button?

I found http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2531.aspx which looks like it does the automatic upload but thats about all I've found so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, when you are trying to show an image after uploading using `ASPxUploadControl` or any other control you have to upload the image on the server.
So, a possible way could be, you can upload the image using `ASPxUploadControl` on the server temporarily and show the image. When user click on `OK` button, move this image from this temporary directory to final directory. And if user doesn't click on `OK` or click on `cancel`, then delete that image from temporary directory. So, either way that temporary directory will be always free.